# Subgroup acting on subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_8$ that act on $\Omega =
> > \{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\},\{7,8\}\}$. Find $|G|$ by using a
>   homomorphism $\Phi:G \rightarrow Perm(\Omega)$ where $\Phi(g) =
> > \sigma_g$, a permutation of elements of $\Omega$ by action of $G$.
>   Then show the center of $G$ is not trivial.

I know that we can work for each permutation, there are multiple possible $h \in H$ since $h$ acts on a set. Also, we can count how many permutations of the set there are, but now I am stuck.

Comment: There is not enough information here. For all we know the subgroup could be trivial.

Comment: see the edited version above

Comment: robnell, again, given your "new" account, Do NOT vandalize your post and render it incomprehensible.  You received an upvoted answer, and upon the submission of your question, you no longer own it.  And don't you dare touch the answerer's answer, which you tried to destroy through an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label the elements of $\Omega$ as $I:=\{1,2\}$, $II:=\{3,4\}$, $III:=\{5,6\}$, $IV:=\{7,8\}$.

It is clear that $\Phi(gh)=\Phi(g)\Phi(h)$, so we have a homomorphism from $G$ into the symmetric group on the four letters $I,II,III,IV$.

But $\Phi$ is onto since (a)  every transposition occurs in the image, for example $(I\ II)=\Phi((13)(24))$; (b) every permutation is a product of transpositions.

The kernel of $\Phi$ is easy to find; it is the set of permutations fixing each of the four sets $I,II, III, IV$ which is just $\langle (12), (34), (56), (78) \rangle$, an abelian group of order $16$.

Hence by the Isomorphism Theorem $|G|= 16. 4!$.

To see the centre is not trivial it is enough to find one non-trivial central element. Consider $(12)(34)(56)(78)$. For any $g\in G$ the element $g^{-1}(12)(34)(56)(78) g$  (a) lies in $\ker\Phi$, since kernels are normal subgroups and (b) is a product of $4$ transpositions, since conjugacy preserves cycle-shape. But $\ker\Phi=\langle (12), (34), (56), (78)\rangle$ has only one element which is a product of $4$ transpositions, so that $g^{-1}(12)(34)(56)(78) g=(12)(34)(56)(78)$, and so $(12)(34)(56)(78)$ is central in $G$.